# update from statement in SQL Server 2008 execution efficiency

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have such functions in SQL Server 2008, the execution time is so long.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_SourcePayin](
    [sourcePayinId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [checkPeriod] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [kdDeptId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [zxDeptId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [amount] [decimal](18, 6) NOT NULL,
    [processDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [operatorId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [manual] [bit] NULL,
    [disabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [chargeTypeId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [nono] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [kdDeptCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [zxDeptCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [hlDeptCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [cwClass] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [outin] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [chargeItem] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [kdHsDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [zxHsDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [kdRatio] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [zxRatio] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [kdjjRatio] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [zxjjRatio] [decimal](8, 6) NULL,
    [ekdRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [ezxRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [freemark] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [freeType] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [jmRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [dfRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [mzRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [zyRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [ejmRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [edfRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [emzRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [ezyRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [kdDoctor] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [kdDoctorNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [qtjjratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [hljjratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [hlDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [hlhsDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [qtDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [qtHsDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [qtratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [eqtRatio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [hlratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [ehlratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [quantity] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
    [patientId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [patientName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [kdysDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [zxysDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [yjDeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [hldydeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ysratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [kdysratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [zxysratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [yjratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [hldyratio] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [lc] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [chargeitemName] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [ysdeptId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [epayinRuleId] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [payinRuleId] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [jjpayinRuleId] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T_SourcePayin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [checkPeriod] ASC,
    [sourcePayinId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Index [IX_T_SourcePayin]    Script Date: 05/21/2013 09:27:41 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_T_SourcePayin] ON [dbo].[T_SourcePayin] 
(
    [checkPeriod] ASC,
    [chargeItem] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Table T_sourcepayin have 100k rows per month.
  This is a map table named t_mapinter as follows about 100 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_MapInter](
    [type] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [inID] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [inName] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [outID] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [outName] [varchar](64) NULL,
    [ratio] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lastUsedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [lastUsedInter] [varchar](32) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In my project, I use a `T_sourcepayinT` get a month data, and then insert into it, update from t_mapinter about 20 times,as follows:

```
  truncate table t_sourcepayint
--delete index


--31s or 60s
insert into t_sourcepayint
select * from t_sourcepayin where checkPeriod = '201305'

-- create index for t_sourcepayint
        /****** Object:  Index [idx_unc_oi_i_sid_cid]    Script Date: 03/17/2013 10:03:25 ******/
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_unc_oi_i_sid_cid] ON [dbo].[t_sourcepayint] 
        (
            [outin] ASC
        )
        INCLUDE ( [sourcePayinId],
        [chargeItem]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]


        /****** Object:  Index [IX_t_sourcepayint]    Script Date: 03/17/2013 10:03:26 ******/
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_t_sourcepayint] ON [dbo].[t_sourcepayint] 
        (
            [chargeItem] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

        /****** Object:  Index [IX_t_sourcepayint_kdhsdeptid]    Script Date: 03/17/2013 10:03:26 ******/
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_t_sourcepayint_kdhsdeptid] ON [dbo].[t_sourcepayint] 
        (
            [kdHsDeptId] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

        /****** Object:  Index [IX_t_sourcepayint_zxhsDeptID]    Script Date: 03/17/2013 10:03:26 ******/
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_t_sourcepayint_zxhsDeptID] ON [dbo].[t_sourcepayint] 
        (
            [zxHsDeptId] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

--update as follows
update a set kdhsdeptid = b.inID
from t_sourcepayint a, (select * from t_mapinter ) b
where a.kddeptid = b.outid

update a set zxhsdeptid = b.inID
from t_sourcepayint a, (select * from t_mapinter ) b
where a.zxdeptid = b.outid

-- t_chargeitem have about 10k rows
update a set kdratio = b.ratio
from t_sourcepayint a, (select chargeitem,ratio from t_chargeitem ) b
where a.kddeptid = 'D000034' and a.chargeitem = b.chargeitem


update a set kdratio = b.ratio
from t_sourcepayint a, (select chargeitem,ratio from t_chargeitem ) b
where a.kddeptid in ('D000038','D000056') and a.chargeitem = b.chargeitem

......

-- update back to t_sourcepayin about 120s 
update a set kdratio = b.kdratio,zxratio = b.zxratio, kdjjratio = b.kdjjratio, ...
from t_sourcepayin a, t_sourcepayint b
where a.checkPeriod = '201305' and a.sourcepayinID = b.sourcepayinID
```

The `execut time` sum is 5 minutes.

How can improve execution efficiency? Change the execute seq or create more efficient index for table T_sourcepayinT or t_sourcepayin.

`update insert` may be another way?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Combine queries so that they don't have to read multiple times. I.e : update a set kdratio = b.ratio -- Avoid SELECT *, join and filter more when possible (i.e insert join join, rather than insert update update) and eliminate bad indexs, if they don't help, they hurt.

Comment: thanks! old-style join in select statement, I get it.

Comment: According to marc_s and Pirion suggestions, I should avoid using * in select and kick using old-style join.